# Select all element of the DOM with javascript except all the children of a particular element

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility

I'm trying to build an accessibility tool in order to enlarge and decrease all the characters in my websites.
So far so good, I created three buttons to increase, decrease and reset the size of my letters, but I've got a problem. I want to select all elements except the letters in my header, in this particular case, all the children of my header, doesn't matter what tag they are.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="text-size">
      <a href="" id="text-shrink">A</a><a href="" id="text-reset">A</a><a href="" id="text-enlarge">A</a>
</div>
```

THE JAVASCRIPT (mixed with jQuery):

```
function resizeText(multiplier) {
    var allElements = document.querySelectorAll( 'body *' );
    for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
        if (allElements[i].style.fontSize == '' || multiplier == 0) {
            allElements[i].style.fontSize = '15px';
        }
        allElements[i].style.fontSize = parseInt(allElements[i].style.fontSize) + multiplier + "px";
    }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#text-shrink').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        resizeText(-1);
    });
    $('#text-reset').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        resizeText(0);
    });
    $('#text-enlarge').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        resizeText(1);
    });
});
```

I tried something like:

```
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll( 'body *:not(header)' );
```

but it didn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Nice job proactively making your site accessible! This is not a great job for Javascript (by itself), I highly recommend you look into using `rem` units in CSS for your font sizes and using JS to adjust the top level font size. This article could help: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/

Comment: I second Rob, but to answer your question: `document.querySelectorAll( 'body *:not(header, header *)' );`

Comment: Hey Karl!
Thank you for suggestion, but from your fix I'm receiving this error:
Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'body *:not(header, header *)' is not a valid selector

Comment: Wouldn't `:not(header *)` be invalid ?

Comment: It is invalid, it didn't work!

Comment: The problem is, `:not` only filters by simple selectors, so you're excluding `header` but not all it's descendants, as they are picked up by `*` as well. I think the easiest would be to do `if ( !(h1Elements[i].closest('header')) )` in the loop

Comment: Or just use jQuery, which supports `header *` in not -> `$('body *').not('header, header *')`

Comment: Hey Adeneo! Your answer works, could you add it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @adeneo well, we learn something new every day, didn't know `:not` only accept *simple* selector. Thanks

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - it's really hard to keep track of these things, as it works just fine in jQuery, it's just in `querySelector` it's not supported

Comment: I always try to avoid to use jQuery, but still, it's so useful, dirty and fast that I will never give up on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to do this, that stores the initial font-size of all elements, and then resets them, so you don't have to have all your elements set to a font-size of `15px`.

It excludes the headers as well

```js
function resizeText(multiplier) {
    $('body *').not('header, header *').css('font-size', function(_,val) {
     return multiplier === 0 ? $(this).data('default_font') : (+val.replace(/\D+/g,'')) + multiplier;
    })
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body *').each(function() {
      $(this).data('default_font', +$(this).css('font-size').replace(/\D+/g,'') || 15);
    });
    
    $('#text-shrink').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        resizeText(-1);
    });
    $('#text-reset').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        resizeText(0);
    });
    $('#text-enlarge').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        resizeText(1);
    });
});
```

```css
#test {font-size : 30px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="text-size">
        <a href="" id="text-shrink">A</a> --- <a href="" id="text-reset">A</a> --- <a href="" id="text-enlarge">A</a>
  </div>
</header>
<br />
<div id="test">TEST</div>
<div >TEST 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay your going to need to update your css not individual elements sizes.
CSS

```
html,body {font-size:100%;}
//Header example
h1 {font-size:2.5rem;}
```

Javascript/jquery/angular
Set a cookie for the user that says they are "X" variable that will than inject the following css into body element of the site so that on each page load it says: "is this cookie there and what is it's value"

```
if(textSizeCookieVal){$('body').css('font-size','120%')'}
```

**Alternatively: and possibly easier**...Set a class on the body that will set the font-size of the body to be certain levels of "%" and set all the other fonts as rems.

thats the fastest way to get the job done right.

*Also to make something truly accessible you would need to set all fonts to REM or EM so that the tools will make the font larger or smaller as a whole. We do something like this at the state*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem of your approach is that I'm working on a client website, built with a theme, so the best approach to avoid to mess up with the stylesheet and so on is just using this dirty fix with javascript. Thank you though, I appreciate and I'm gonna build this very tool that you suggested for a website that I'm gonna build

Comment: inject your own css than...thats basically just rewriting font sizes based on body classes